# vhost working but not finding index.php

Tags: localhost, magento, virtualhost

Its my first time that i have a vserver with plesk - i always deleted plesk and worked without it because i didnt liked it but now i try with and it doesnt work as i want it.

installed magento here:

```
/var/www/name/public_html/magento/public
```

my vhost is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost.name.com
ServerAlias www.localhost.name.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/name/public_html/magento/public

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/www/name/public_html/magento/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/name/public_html/magento/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my hosts file on my mac is this one:

```
serverip localhost.name.com
```

not

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.name.com
```

if i now type localhost.name.com in my browser plesk says that this is Web Server's Default Page so i assume its working. but when i try to install magento (localhost.name.com/index.php/install) it says "The requested URL /index.php/install was not found on this server."

But i checked it via ls /var/www/name/public_html/magento/public and all my magento files are installed.

Comment: Did you enable mod_rewrite?

Comment: what happens if you ping localhost.name.com?